# WPF: Binding an Image to Integer-DB-Field

Tags: database, image, binding

I am learning WPF since a couple of weeks but now I've got a problem which I havent solved yet. I'm playin with my Telephone Line and when a new Call is Incoming I set an Integer in the Database to "1". When the Line is active I set it to "2" ... When the Line is open the Integer is "0". In my WPF-Application I got a small Image like a little green LED for example. When a Call comes in / the line is blocked/active it have to be a red LED for example. I've read many articles about DataTrigger and EventTrigger but I doesnt know if this is the right starting point.

Can anyone give me a little hint for me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this. If you are using MVVM (and you probably should be), then you could have a string property on your view model which returns the appropriate image path based on the value of the integer. Then you can bind an `Image` control's `Source` value to the property on your view model in the view.

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImagePathStringProperty}" Width="32" Height="32" />
```

Alternatively, you could expose this integer property to your view, and use a `DataTrigger` to set the image source based on this integer value.

```
<Image>
  <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/MyDefaultImage.png" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyIntegerProperty}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/MyFirstImage.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyIntegerProperty}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/MySecondImage.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyIntegerProperty}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/MyThirdImage.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Can u tell me how this "MyIntegerProperty" have to look like? This Prob is makin me terrible...

Comment: Are you using MVVM? i.e. is the data context for the view an instance of a view model? In this case, your view model would implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and have an integer property on it (with a getter and setter), and in the setter, it would invoke the PropertyChanged event. This tells the UI to retrieve the new integer value and update the binding (in this case, updating your image). Read more about MVVM here - http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html

Comment: hey, no im not using MVVM.
I have read many articles and now i want to use an ObservableCollection beacuse they got the CollectionChanged - Event ... when i declare the ObservableCollection it looks like this:
ObservableCollection<DatabaseEntity> collection = new ObservableCollection<DatabaseEntity>(_context.DatabaseEntity);
after that i set the CollectionChanged-event like this:
collection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collection_CollectionChanged)

Comment: But the CollectionChanged-Event doenst Fire if i change the Integer-Value in the Entity

Comment: No, it wouldn't. The ObservableCollection doesn't consider a change in a property of an underlying data object to be a change to the collection. You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your underlying data type (i.e. DatabaseEntity). In the setter for the property, you should invoke the PropertyChanged event. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx for details.